# Building GNU Make using MinGW - errors in build_w32.bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, gcc

The README document (for versions 3.81 and 4.1) directs running the command 
`build_w32.bat gcc` from the command prompt. On running this, it complains that certain .o files are "not found", particularly:

gcc: error: job.o: No such file or directory

Specifically, the errors are:

```
C:\MAKE\make-3.81>gcc -mthreads -Wall -gstabs+ -ggdb3 -O2 -I. -I./glob -I./w32/include -DWINDOWS32 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -c job.c 

In file included from make.h:22:0,
             from job.c:19:

./config.h:425:19: error: duplicate 'unsigned'

 #define uintmax_t unsigned long
               ^
./config.h:425:28: error: 'long long long' is too long for GCC

 #define uintmax_t unsigned long
```

Commenting the first line doesn't seem to help. Also, no define to "long long long" is made anywhere in `config.h`.

Searching the web for ways to solve this doesn't yield any satisfactory results. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by commenting out the two defines mentioned above, and un-commenting the line `#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1`.